# asp.net mvc multiple dropdrownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a form that loads some Partial Views dinamically and one of these Partial Views will load multiple dropdownlists in the screen.

I have a ViewModel (principal): used in the main view

```
public class CupomFiscalDetalhesViewModel
{
    //some properties
    public IEnumerable<CupomItensViewModel> CupomItens { get; set; }
}
```

An intermediate ViewModel: the view model of the partial view:

```
public class CupomItensViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<TabelaPrecoViewModel> TabelasPreco { get; set; }
    public TabelaPrecoViewModel TabelaPrecoSelecionada { get; set; }
}
```

Where `TabelaPrecos` is holding the values that I want to show in the DropDownList. and `TabelaPrecoSelecionada` will hold the selected value.

In the Controller, I'm used to put the values of an IEnumerable into a ViewBag, and use this ViewBag to generate the dropdownlist in the HTML, like this:

```
ViewBag.TabelaPrecoSelecionada = new SelectList
(
     detalhesCupomFiscal.CupomItens.FirstOrDefault().TabelasPreco,
     "IdTabela",
     "NomeTabela"
);
```

But I have no idea how to generate multiple dropdowns for each option of `CupomItensViewModel`, without passing the id of the selected value of each dropdownlist to the controller action (by parameter).

In the Html, I use: but would need to change the name to get binding workin somehow.

```
@Html.DropDownList("TabelaPrecoSelecionada",(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.TabelaPrecoSelecionada,
new { @class = "form-control dropdown" })
```

Does anyone has an Idea how to accomplish it?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't test this but I would maybe create the select list inside your CupomItensViewModel

```
using System.Linq;
public class CupomItensViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<TabelaPrecoViewModel> TabelasPreco { get; set; }
    public TabelaPrecoViewModel TabelaPrecoSelecionada { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> TabelasPrecoSelectList
    {
        get 
        {
           return TabelasPreco.Select(x => new SelectListItem() 
                  {
                    Value = x.IdTabela
                    Text = x.NomeTabela
                    Selected = TabelaPrecoSelecionada.IdTabela
                  }
        }
    }
}
```

And Inside your view

```
@foreach(var item in Model.CupomItens)
{
  @Html.DropDownList("TabelaPrecoSelecionada", item.TabelasPrecoSelectList, new { @class = "form-control dropdown" })
}
```

But if these dropdowns aren't going to be next to each other, I would make

```
public IEnumerable<CupomItensViewModel> CupomItens { get; set; }
```

List instead and using index to identify them. CupomItens[x]

Just my 2 cent without checking if it works. Hopefully it helps.

Comment: Hey @Tek, thanks for answering,
Man, What I have is many dropdowns as I said before, I'm trying to implement this property as an IEnumerable of SelectListItem, but the Selected requires a boolean and the way you've done it's passing the IdTabela

Comment: My VIew is using an For Loop:
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++), where I have some hidden itens such as <input type="hidden" name="CupomItens[@i].CodigoProduto" value="@Model[i].CodigoProduto" />  

The dropdowns should have a similar way to put in it's name "CupomItens[@i].SomethingHere"